# Are ride request waypoints updated according to their progress?

Tags: uber-api

Are ride requests waypoints updated according to their progress?

Here's what I would expect when picking up and dropping off another rider:

- Pickup and dropoff waypoints added for that rider added to waypoints
- Once rider is picked up, his pickup waypoint is removed from waypoints
- Once rider is dropped off, his dropoff waypoint is removed from waypoints

Are my expectations matching actual behavior? Or would all the waypoints stay populated in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we believe your understanding is correct, but this only applies to POOL trips.

Comment: Are you able to confirm this is how it's going to happen in production? or do you know a way I can validate this in sandbox?

Comment: Were you able to validate the info [@kyle-davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6377424/kyle-davis) ?

Comment: There isn't a way to test/confirm this in Sandbox for pool trips. In production you will see this work as expected and we did confirm this behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Accepting answer :)